# Yii2: Calculation using JQuery based on condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a form with fields with ID like

`#opdtestbill-health_card_number`
`#opdtestbill-test_charges`
`#opdtestbill-discount`
`#opdtestbill-total_charges`

Now what I am trying to do is when the health_card_number is not empty calculate discount on test charges. That is the discount field and total_charges field is filled automatically.

The test_charges field is getting the data through ajax and is not filled manually.

I have tried this code, but I am getting `NaN` in both discount and total_charges.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("$('#opdtestbill-health_card_number').blur(function(){
        if( $(this).val() ) {
        var test_charges = parseInt($('#opdtestbill-test_charges').val());
        var discount = (test_charges*5)/100;
        var totalAmount = test_charges - discount;
        $('#opdtestbill-discount').val(discount);
        $('#opdtestbill-total_charges').val(totalAmount);  
         }else{        
        $('#opdtestbill-discount').val()=0; 
         } 
});"); 
?>
```

I have not much idea about using JQuery, any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried to do this using only php, but it works only on update, not on new record.
The php code I am using is like
in my **Model**

```
public function getHealthCardDiscount(){
        $discount=0;
        if (!empty($this->health_card_number)){
        $discount = ($this->test_charges *5)/100;
        }
        return $discount;
    }
```

and in **_form.php**

```
$model->discount=$model->healthCardDiscount;

$model->total_charges=$model->test_charges - $model->healthCardDiscount;
```

Thanks.

HTML for relevant section is like this:

```
<div class="form-group field-opdtestbill-health_card_number">
<label class="control-label" for="opdtestbill-health_card_number">Health Crd. No.</label>
<input type="text" id="opdtestbill-health_card_number" class="form-control" name="OpdTestBill[health_card_number]" maxlength="15">

<div class="form-group field-opdtestbill-test_charges">
<label class="control-label" for="opdtestbill-test_charges">Test Charges</label>
<input type="text" id="opdtestbill-test_charges" class="form-control" name="OpdTestBill[test_charges]" maxlength="10">

<div class="form-group field-opdtestbill-discount">
<label class="control-label" for="opdtestbill-discount">Disct.</label>
<input type="text" id="opdtestbill-discount" class="form-control" name="OpdTestBill[discount]" maxlength="10">

<div class="form-group field-opdtestbill-total_charges">
<label class="control-label" for="opdtestbill-total_charges">Total Charges</label>
<input type="text" id="opdtestbill-total_charges" class="form-control" name="OpdTestBill[total_charges]" value="0" maxlength="10">
```

**Rendered Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#opdtestbill-health_card_number').blur(function(){
        if( $(this).val() ) {
        var test_charges = parseInt($('#opdtestbill-test_charges').val());
        var discount = (test_charges*5)/100;
        var totalAmount = test_charges - discount;
        $('#opdtestbill-discount').val(discount);
        $('#opdtestbill-total_charges').val(totalAmount);  
         }else{        
        $('#opdtestbill-discount').val()=0; 
         } 
});
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML and JavaScript instead of the PHP code? That's going to make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want convert string to integer, you may use like that:

```
var test = "10";
test = test - 0;
```

And you make error in this

`$('#opdtestbill-discount').val()=0;`

I change your js code see http://jsfiddle.net/vitalik74/upLbpnmk/

Comment: Thanks so much @vitalik you are awesome. I just need a little modification, can you please suggest that it will always calculate test_charges minus discount instead of blur function. only % will be calculated if health_card is not empty. Thank you so much.

Comment: Change `blur(function(){` to `keyup(function(){`

Comment: Thanks You once Again.